# How to solve 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T[]'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I found this function:

```
function sliceIntoChunks(arr, chunkSize) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
    res.push(chunk);
  }
  return res;
}
```

and I want to type it:

```
export const sliceIntoChunks = <T>(
  arr: Array<T>,
  chunkSize: number
): Array<T> => {
  const res: T[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
    res.push(chunk);
  }
  return res;
};
```

Getting an error here: `res.push(chunk);`

error:

> Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
> unrelated to 'T[]'.

How do I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resulting array will be array of arrays, so:

```
const sliceIntoChunks = <T>(
  arr: Array<T>,
  chunkSize: number
): Array<T[]> => {
  const res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
    res.push(chunk);
  }
  return res;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBA2BLYBTAkmKIDCALArmANYQwC8MAPACoA0AfABQCwAUDDAIYBO3AXDACCvTgE8a9Wmw7ACxAMqIAXigFh8AWwBGKbmwCUA4dzE0A2gF165awG9pMUJFjcUpCpYDcbBwDMQ3DCM8CiwiOQwAAyeMOGUXLwAdCFgAOZQuDHhANQUsoREiir6MPbsHI7g0I5yRBE83IkIyCiMiLSxMNk1BUUo%20t7lHK4QiQAO%20BC4jPnEAw4Avg6uUPjcYDAjgwuDbE4QICHJIKmMzagYWHgFEIxmAIwdAEwdAMwdACwdAKwdAGwdADsHQAHB0AJwde6RCxvfT6IA)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.slice` returns an array, a subset of `arr`. So If `arr` is of type `Array<T>`, then `chunk` is too. But `res` is also of type `Array<T>` (or the equivalent `T[]`), so `res.push` expects an argument of type `T`, not `Array<T>`.

Try changing the type of `res` from `T[]` to `T[][]`.